# Why is hasFile() undefined in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 9, I want to store the users' photos in a database, but when I try to register, it displays this message although I've included Illuminate\Http\Request and the enctype:
***Call to undefined method App\Models\Student::hasfile()***

```
if($e->hasfile('photo')){
           $file = $req->file('photo');
           $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
           $file->move('public/students', $filename);
           $e->photo = $filename;
       }
```

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="custom-file-input">
```

And when I use hasOne(), it says that Class 'photo' is not found, what to do?

Comment: What's the _complete_ error message? Did you `dump($e)` to see what it contains?

Comment: I've dump($e), when I look closely, I notice that test is false.

Comment: The full message: Call to undefined method App\Models\Student::hasfile() /// Bad Method Call
Did you mean App\Models\Student::hasOne() ?

Comment: `hasFile()` is for `Request` models. You used the `Student` model. `if($e->hasfile('photo')){` should most likely be `if($req->hasfile('photo')){`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if($e->has('photo')){ // you need to use has() function instead of hasfile()
       $file = $req->file('photo');
       $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
       $file->move('public/students', $filename);
       $e->photo = $filename;
 }
```

I hope it was useful !